# Finding most bought Items together from list of orders--

Tags: python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, jupyter-notebook

My requirement is as below:

1. For an Order max of 20 line items can be added (20 - Columns)
2. There are N number order list with 20 line Items (N - Row)

With the above data set - I need to find out what are the line items bought together.
For an example -

Examples - In the N number of order list there are like
Few Orders has all the 20 line items same.
Few Orders has 15 line Items Same
Few Orders has 10/9/8/7/6/5 line items bought together.[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly82R.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyHii.png)

So Output should looks like -
NoOfLineItems** LineItems **                               HowManyTimes
20              Item1..Item20(list all the 20 items)       45
11              Item2,Item40,...(list all the 11 Items)    378
7               Item45, Item33,..(list all the 7 Items)    67890

Please give your valuable input for this, thanks in advance!

Input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWa72.png)

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQHc.png)

Comment: Please let me know if any more information needed.

Comment: Have a go with sumif(), sumifs() or countif() & countifs().

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community hi i have added the input and expected output - Could you please guide me

Comment: @SolarMike Could you please guide me with the example please, i have added new images with input and expected output.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/error messages. Post the formatted text directly here on SO. Also, what have you tried, why did it fail? I assume based on your tags you are looking for an Excel solution? Why is it tagged Python, then?

Comment: Excel has examples of all of those functions, have you checked them? Also, you will find examples of their use on here.

Comment: The output would generate an immense list of combinations. Imagine the number of rows containing a combination of 2 of the same. If you list all it will not give you a good insight would be my guess. Maybe limit it to a minimum number of resembling  line items per row.

Comment: @P.b yeah with 2 it will generate more number of combinations.. I am looking for 5 or more combinations but struggling  to  code this ..

Comment: @Mr.T I have tried countif and countifs in excel but here I am only getting number of times particular number is getting repeated not the subset of repetitive numbers

Comment: @SolarMike I have tried countif and countifs but here I am only getting cmnumber of times each item repeated not the commonly bought items

Comment: Hi all to rephrase, I have 20 line items of 20k+ orders .. I want to fetch most  repetitive items bought together in orders .. for example all the 20 items match and count , 19 items match and count , 18 items match and count …. Matching criteria Will be minimum of 7 and above items .. I tried sum and countif it did not help.. could you please give me some advice